# Gson escapes the escape sequences again while converting to json - Android

Tags: json, string, kotlin, gson, retrofit

I'm trying to send a html string to server.
The html that I have:

```
val htmlInput = "<div>ansi nmasbnmbsanbdmnsbmndbsanbdnbsand<br></div><div><span class=\"size\" style=\"font-size: 16px\">ggsgjfgjfdgfgdg</span><br></div><div><br></div><div><span class=\"size\" style=\"font-size: 16px\">fgsdgfd</span><br></div><div><br></div><div><br></div><div><ul><li>fgsfgdf<br></li></ul><div><br></div><div><ol><li>fgdsg<br></li><li>sdfgsd<br></li><li>sfgs<br></li><li>sdfg<br></li><li>gfdsffgf<br></li></ol><div><br></div><blockquote style=\"background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245); padding: 7px; border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);\"><div><div><span class=\"colour\" style=\"color:rgba(57, 229, 0, 2.6)\"><span class=\"highlight\" style=\"background-color:rgba(255, 64, 0, 2.6)\">jfkdsfsdfsfsdfs</span></span><br></div></div></blockquote></div><div><br></div><div>ajjfajfjajfjf<br></div><div><br></div><table border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"2\" cellspacing=\"2\" style=\"width: 100%;\"><tbody><tr><td>afafsadfasfdsa</td><td>ddadasdadadasd</td></tr><tr><td>adadasdasd</td><td>asdadadasdasda</td></tr></tbody></table><div><br></div><div><br></div></div><div><br></div>"
```

Now I'm trying to construct the input json using gson like

```
val inputData = mapOf("input" to htmlInput)
val gson = GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create()
val inputDataString = gson.toJson(inputData)
```

Now, the inputDataString obtained from the above code is like,

```
{ "input" : "<div>ansi nmasbnmbsanbdmnsbmndbsanbdnbsand<br><\/div><div><span class=\\\"size\\\" style=\\\"font-size: 16px\\\">ggsgjfgjfdgfgdg<\/span><br><\/div><div><br><\/div><div><span class=\\\"size\\\" style=\\\"font-size: 16px\\\">fgsdgfd<\/span><br><\/div><div><br><\/div><div><br><\/div><div><ul><li>fgsfgdf<br><\/li><\/ul><div><br><\/div><div><ol><li>fgdsg<br><\/li><li>sdfgsd<br><\/li><li>sfgs<br><\/li><li>sdfg<br><\/li><li>gfdsffgf<br><\/li><\/ol><div><br><\/div><blockquote style=\\\"background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245); padding: 7px; border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);\\\"><div><div><span class=\\\"colour\\\" style=\\\"color:rgba(57, 229, 0, 2.6)\\\"><span class=\\\"highlight\\\" style=\\\"background-color:rgba(255, 64, 0, 2.6)\\\">jfkdsfsdfsfsdfs<\/span><\/span><br><\/div><\/div><\/blockquote><\/div><div><br><\/div><div>ajjfajfjajfjf<br><\/div><div><br><\/div><table border=\\\"1\\\" cellpadding=\\\"2\\\" cellspacing=\\\"2\\\" style=\\\"width: 100%;\\\"><tbody><tr><td>afafsadfasfdsa<\/td><td>ddadasdadadasd<\/td><\/tr><tr><td>adadasdasd<\/td><td>asdadadasdasda<\/td><\/tr><\/tbody><\/table><div><br><\/div><div><br><\/div><\/div><div><br><\/div>" }
```

I can't figure out why Gson is further escaping the string which is properly escaped. Suggest me what I have to change to make the above code working.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Everything is fine, if we keep quotes as `"`, JSON format will be broken, like:

```
{
 "a" : ""b"
}
```

but with backslash protection (escape the characters) `"\""` is ok:

```
{
 "a": "\"b"
}
```

---

> I'm trying to send a html string to server.

If the request has `"content-type", "application/json"`, your server-side should handle it. Nothing to do on your side

---

about `disableHtmlEscaping`:

> By default, Gson escapes HTML characters such as < > etc. Use this option to configure Gson to pass-through HTML characters as is.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I have 'class=\"size\"' and while constructing json with this string results in modifying 1 backward slash to 3 backward slashes. Is that fine?

Comment: for input `"<div class="size"></div>"` you should get `{"input": "<div class=\"size\">/div>"}`.      For input `<div class=\"size\"></div>` you should get `{"input": "<div class=\\\"size\\\"></div>"}`